# MongoDB+Scala: Accessing deep nested data

Tags: mongodb, scala, nested, casbah

I think there should be an easy solution around, but I wasn't able to find it.

I start accessing data from MongoDB with the following in Scala:

```
val search = MongoDBObject("_id" -> new ObjectId("xxx"))
val fields = MongoDBObject("community.member.name" -> 1, "community.member.age" -> 1)

for (res <- mongoColl.find(search, fields)) {
    var memberInfo = res.getAs[BasicDBObject]("community").get
    println(memberInfo)
}
```

and get a BasicDBObject as result:

```
{
"member" : [
    {
        "name" : "John Doe",
        "age" : "32",
    },{
        "name" : "Jane Doe",
        "age" : "29",
    },
    ...
]
}
```

I know that I can access values with getAs[String], though this is not working here...
Anyone has an idea? Searching for a solution for several hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try

```
val member = memberInfo.as[MongoDBList]("member").as[BasicDBObject](0)
println(member("name"))
```

Comment: I am suspecting there is a less verbose solution. You can try `memberInfo.as[MongoDBList]("member").as(0)` and see if it can infer the type.

Comment: Also yes, salat is they way to go in the long run. It is an elegant wrapper over casbah.

Answer (score 2):

If you working with complex MongoDB objects, you can use [Salat](https://github.com/novus/salat), which provides simple case class serialization.
Sample with your data:

```
case class Community(members:Seq[Member], _id: ObjectId = new ObjectId)

case class Member(name:String, age:Int)

val mongoColl: MongoCollection = _

val dao = new SalatDAO[Community, ObjectId](mongoColl) {}

val community = Community(Seq(Member("John Doe", 32), Member("Jane Doe", 29)))
dao.save(community)

for {
    c <- dao.findOneById(community._id)
    m <- c.members
} println("%s (%s)" format (m.name, m.age))
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you provide a short example adressing deeper nested data?

Comment: This looks very promising and clearly structured. In the long term I will go for it. But to solve my urgent problem the answer from anoopelias is short and fine. I would like to upvote your post but I have to get some reputation first... will make a task for that later on! :-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This problem has not to do really with MongoDB, but rather with your data structure. Your JSON/BSON data structure includes

- An object community, which includes

  - An array of members

    - Each member has properties name or age.

Your problem is completely equivalent to the following:

```
case class Community(members:List[Member])

case class Member(name:String, age:Int)

val a = List(member1,member2)

// a.name does not compile, name is a property defined on a member, not on the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this beautifully with comprehensions. You could do the following:

```
for { record <- mongoColl.find(search,fields).toList
      community <- record.getAs[MongoDBObject]("community")
      member <- record.getAs[MongoDBObject]("member")
      name <- member.getAs[String]("name") } yield name
```

This would work just to get the name. To get multiple values, I think you would do:

```
for { record <- mongoColl.find(search,fields).toList
      community <- record.getAs[MongoDBObject]("community")
      member <- record.getAs[MongoDBObject]("member")
      field <- List("name","age") } yield member.get(field).toString
```